# How to automate dos2unix using shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, dos2unix

I have a bunch of xml files in a directory that need to have the dos2unix command performed on them and new files will be added every so often.  I Instead of manually performing dos2unix command on each files everytime I would like to automate it all with a script.  I have never even looked at a shell script in my life but so far I have this from what I have read on a few tutorials:

```
FILES=/tmp/testFiles/*
for f in $FILES
do
  fname=`basename $f`
  dos2unix *.xml $f $fname
done
```

However I keep getting the 'usage' output showing up.  I think the problem is that I am not assigning the name of the new file correctly (fname).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason you're getting a usage message is that `dos2unix` doesn't take the extra arguments you're supplying. It will, however, accept multiple filenames (also via globs). You don't need a loop unless you're processing more files than can be accepted on the command line.

```
dos2unix /tmp/testFiles/*.xml
```

Should be all you need, unless you need recursion:

```
find /tmp/testFiles -name '*.xml' -exec dos2unix {} +
```

(for GNU find)

Answer (score 2):

If all files are in one directory (no recursion needed) then you're almost there.

```
for file in /tmp/testFiles/*.xml ; do
    dos2unix "$file"
done
```

By default `dos2unix` should convert in place and overwrite the original.

If recursion is needed you'll have to use `find` as well:

```
find /tmp/testFiles -name '*.xml' -print0 | while IFS= read -d '' file ; do
    dos2unix "$file"
done
```

Which will work on all files ending with `.xml` in `/tmp/testFiles/` and all of its sub-directories.

If no other step are required you can skip the shell loop entirely:

Non-recursive:

```
find /tmp/testFiles -maxdepth 1 -name '*.xml' -exec dos2unix {} +
```

And for recursive:

```
find /tmp/testFiles -name '*.xml' -exec dos2unix {} +
```

In your original command I see you finding the base name of each file name and trying to pass that to `dos2unix`, but your intent is not clear. Later, in a comment, you say you just want to overwrite the files. My solution performs the conversion, creates no backups and overwrites the original with the converted version. I hope this was your intent.

Comment: He's not storing the results of an expanded glob. The glob is not expanded on assignment.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson: I see that you are right. I have removed this comment, thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

```
mkdir /tmp/testFiles/converted/
for f in /tmp/testFiles/*.xml
do
  fname=`basename $f`
  dos2unix $f ${f/testFiles\//testFiles\/converted\/}
  # or for pure sh:
  # dos2unix $f $(echo $f | sed s@testFiles/@testFiles/converted/@)
done
```

The result will be saved in the `converted/` subdirectory.

The construction `${f/testFiles\//testFiles\/converted\/}` (thanks to *Rush*)
or `sed` is used here to add `converted/` before the name of the file:

```
$ echo /tmp/testFiles/1.xml | sed s@testFiles/@testFiles/converted/@
/tmp/testFiles/converted/1.xml
```

Comment: Thank you but can you explain what this does:  "$(echo $f | sed s@testFiles/@testFiles/converted/)"  Edit: this command does not work.  Error:  sed: command garbled: s@testFiles/@testFiles/converted/, removing the sed command gives error:  COuldn't open input file FILES

Comment: I just add `converted/` before that name of the file.

Comment: You don't need `sed` for that. You can do it with `${f/testFiles\//testFiles\/converted\/}`

Comment: @Rush: that works only in bash not in Bourne shell (`/bin/sh`)

Comment: Guys, I want to overwrite the files so moving the new files to another directory isn't an issue.  The above command doesn't work.  Any other suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: What does it mean "doesn't work"? Which error do you get? Can please show the error message?

Comment: @AlanSmith: How about `find /tmp/testFiles/ -maxdepth 1 -type f  -exec dos2unix {} +` (if you dont want to have a backup)?

Comment: @IgorChubin: This question is tagged `bash` and is not tagged `sh` or `shell` or `posix-sh`, so I think bashisms are acceptable.

Answer (score -1):

It is not clear which implementation of dos2unix you are using. Different implementations require different arguments. There are many different implementations around.

On RedHat/Fedora/Suse Linux you could just type

```
    dos2unix /tmp/testFiles/*.xml
```

On SunOS you are required to give an input and output file name, and the above command would destroy several of your files.